# Rigify Rig Issue

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, rigify, vertex-groups

I have used rigify to rig a character. However when I move the neck some vertex of the chest move with it. I gave 100% influence with auto normalization on the chest vertex, but it still moves with the neck. How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: You can select these vertices in Edit mode (enable the Edit and the On Cage options of the Armature modifier), remove them from all groups (function on the right of the Vertex Groups list), then assign them to the correct group